# Laravel 8 Project is not opening in the server..getting error in TestDatabases.php

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am Getting error when I open the laravel 8 project

```
 protected function switchToDatabase($database)
    {
        DB::purge();
 
        $default = config('database.default');
 
        config()->set(
            "database.connections.{$default}.database",
            $database,
        );
    }
```

> *"syntax error, unexpected ')'"* in vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Testing/Concerns/TestDatabases.php

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Gert B. answer does solve the situation, but you should instead update your PHP to version 7.3 or higher, as Mohammad mentioned, to solve this. Changing platform/vendor code is not the best option.

Comment: true, i missed the part that it was a vendor file.. this means he installed with --ignore-platform-reqs, thats not a good idea ... so upvote for this

Comment: @GertB. Not necessarily, might've been running a different (newer) command line version of PHP than Apache/Nginx was running.

Answer (score 10):

You're using a PHP version lower than 7.3

in: `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Testing/Concerns/TestDatabases.php`

Change:

```
    if ($url) {
        config()->set(
            "database.connections.{$default}.url",
            preg_replace('/^(.*)(\/[\w-]*)(\??.*)$/', "$1/{$database}$3", $url),
        );
    } else {
        config()->set(
            "database.connections.{$default}.database",
            $database,
        );
    }
```

to:

```
    if ($url) {
        config()->set(
            "database.connections.{$default}.url",
            preg_replace('/^(.*)(\/[\w-]*)(\??.*)$/', "$1/{$database}$3", $url)
        );
    } else {
        config()->set(
            "database.connections.{$default}.database",
            $database
        );
    }
```

**Removing the comma at the end of line fixes the issue.**

Comment: I had 7.2 version in my local and wanted to set 7.2 in my server. When I changed the code, it worked. Thanks @Mohammad

Answer (score 6):

remove the trailing "," in your set function call:

```
config()->set(
        "database.connections.{$default}.database",
        $database
    );
```

Comment: Not a good solution at all! The file that has been referred to is in the vendor folder. Once `composer update` is executed the problem comes again

Comment: @JonasMerhej true, I missed the part that it was a vendor file.. this means he installed with --ignore-platform-reqs, thats not a good idea ... so I upvoted the answer that commented my mistake quite some time ago.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the "," directly from file placed in vendors folder isn't a good idea.

To resolve the issue update your php version (7.3 or higher).

If you are using valet:

- execute `valet use php@7.3` or higher

If you are using something like vagrant (and apache):

- connet to server via "`vagrant ssh`"
- install php7.3 or higher (`sudo apt install php7.3`) and then the related packages that you want
- disable your current php version via "`sudo a2dismod php7.2`" (if your current version is 7.2)
- enable php7.3 via "`sudo a2enmod php7.3`"
- restart apache "`sudo service apache2 restart`"

Answer (score 2):

**phpinfo() gives you the version of apache which is the actual version the project runs on and in case you want to change it simply follow these steps:**

install php version that you wish to install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php -y
sudo apt-get update

//replace X with the version you want
sudo apt-get install php7.X-fpm php7.X-curl php7.X-mbstring php7.X-mysql -y
```

Now restart your apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

disable current php version(the one that phpinfo() gives you):

```
sudo a2dismod php7.2
```

And now enable php version that you just installed:

```
sudo a2enmod php7.X
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is as stuck on this as I was, here were the steps I followed. If you have the same situation as me, your php versions might be different. I was going from 7.2 to 7.4. I had to:

- Uninstall my old version of php via homebrew

`brew uninstall php@7.2`

- Completely delete the reference I had to that old version of php even though I had uninstalled it via homebrew.

`rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar/php@7.2`

- Unlink all versions except php@7.4. For me that was php@7.2 and php with no version specification.

`brew unlink php`

`brew unlink php@7.2`

Answer (score 0):

For my experience in Ubuntu Linux, check your php version

```
php -v
```

You may switch to require version, install if you don't have php@7.4

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.4
```

Do your requirements. I have migration issue. So

```
php artisan migrate
```

switch back to default version

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.2
```